# Selected row in listview keeps selected index

Tags: c#, listview

I am trying to make a visitor logbook. I have a ListView that has a list of visitors in it.

If you select a visitor and click a button it will remove them from the list by updating a field in the database that indicates they are signed out and then refresh the list to show only the visitors that do not have that field ticked.

```
if (lsvVisitors.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, "Do you wish to sign-out " 
        + lsvVisitors.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text + " " 
        + lsvVisitors.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text),
        "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question) 
            == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var entry = _repository.GetLogbookEntryById((LogbookEntry)lsvVisitors.SelectedItems[0].Tag);
        _repository.SignOutLogbookEntry(entry);
        UpdateList();
    }   
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
        "You need to select a Visitor to sign-out"), 
        "Warning", 
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
        MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
```

My problem is that when the user clicked on the signout button with no one selected in the list I had to check that the selecteditems count is > 0 and if it failed this check I tell the user to select someone in the list. Now, if the user selects someone and then the focus is removed off the listview and it appears that the visitor is not selected the selected items is still showing as the last person selected in the list.

I can't reset this on when the focus leaves the box because then they won't be able to sign out a user ever with the sign out button.

I am asking, how do I reset the selecteditems.count for my listview if the item is no longer visibly selected in the list only?

Comment: It should still be selected when you lose focus i think ..

Comment: yes Noctis, it has to be selected

Comment: Yeah. I want it to keep the selected item when focus changes to the  signout button but if the focus changes at any other occasion I want it to lose the selected item. Is this possible?

Comment: you want to keep the selected item when focus changes to signout button and you want to listview to loose the selected item if focus changes from signout button right, yes its possible.

Comment: You'll have to manually set the selectedItem in the other places, where you want it unselected. Something like `lsvVisitors.SelectedIndex = -1`

Comment: I don't really get what you're asking. Do you mean, after I select a visitor, then click "Sign Out", the selectedItems still contain the one that you remove? If that's the case, can you clear the selectedItems?

Comment: It's ok, I have the solution now. I have a search box and when I change focus to the search box the selected item in the listview loses the actual blue background to show it is selected but if I click on the sign out button it will remain as the selected index. I will just put the code Noctis suggests in the search text box event when it gets focus. If I click off on the listview itself it loses the selected index and any other object I have doesn't relate to it anyway.

Comment: would you like me to post it as an answer , or shall i vote to close this question otherwise?

Comment: @Noctis can you post the answer please? I have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Since **Ashes999** asked, here's an example: [zip with solution and demo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b94yl68gucobxmu/remove%20selected%20index.zip)

It's based on this article I wrote for the code projec: [Selected value, index and more](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/671544/Understanding-SelectedValue-SelectedValuePath-Sele).

I've added a textbox at the bottom, and wired the `OnFocus` event to set the listbox selected index to -1. This way, you can have changing focus to reset the selected index to -1 on objects you want, and leave it as is for your submission button.

If you wanna skip the demo (a shame really, but hey, who knows...), here's the XAML:

```
 <TextBox Text="Click here to remove index"  GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus"  />
```

and here's the code behind:

```
private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.SourceListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

(Note, you'll need a `ListBox` called `SourceListBox`, or to rename it accordingly)